# RubyMine support for jQuery

Tags: jquery, rubymine

I'm using RubyMine 3.1 to develop a Rails3 app and today I switched from Prototype to jQuery for my UJS needs.

After customizing everything using [this example](http://www.stjhimy.com/posts/7-creating-a-100-ajax-crud-using-rails-3-and-unobtrusive-javascript) and restarting RubyMine, all the auto-complete suggestions and the code inspector errors are still being based on Prototype.

What else should I do to get the JavaScript code completion & Co. tailored to jQuery?

*(related to: [Remove Prototype support from RubyMine: how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239297/remove-prototype-support-from-rubymine-how-to))*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This article to [enable jQuery code completion in RubyMine](http://www.unfoldingcode.com/2011/04/jquery-support-in-rubymine.html) describes these steps:

1. go to **Settings**, then **JavaScript Libraries** and add a new library;
2. in **Usage Scope**, enable the library for the current project;
3. done!

Answer (score 1):

Please watch/vote for the [issue in the bug tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-5026).

Comment: Voted/watching the issue on JetBrains' bugtracker and also left a comment describing my scenario. I couldn't help but notice that this issue was **submitted 17 months ago** and updated 9 months ago with no plans to get it fixed. Do you have any ideas of possible fixes?

Comment: Check http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/11/javascript-libraries-in-intellij-idea-10/. If RubyMine has the same feature, it may help.