# Remove Prototype support from RubyMine: how to?

Tags: prototypejs, rubymine

I'm using RubyMine 3.1 to develop my Rails3 app and today I switched from Prototype to jQuery for my UJS needs.

Customized everything using [this example](http://www.stjhimy.com/posts/7-creating-a-100-ajax-crud-using-rails-3-and-unobtrusive-javascript) and restarted RubyMine, yet all the auto-complete suggestions and the code inspector errors are still being based on Prototype.

How can I remove all the JavaScript code completion & Co. tailored to Prototype?

*(related to: [RubyMine support for jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237153/rubymine-support-for-jquery))*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a new Rails application, pass the `--skip-prototype` flag, e.g.:

```
$ rails new myCommentsApp --skip-prototype
```

This way Prototype will not be bundled with your app and RubyMine will also not autocomplete based on Prototype.

Here you can also find an efficient step by step approach to [switching the JS library in your Rails app](http://www.unfoldingcode.com/2011/04/enabling-ujs-in-rails3-with-jquery-3.html).